# I am trying to loop through an array and find each object that has said keyword in a property

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

So I want to set this variable to all of the objects in an array in which its category has a certain keyword.
This is what I have so far

```
  let tempMensProducts = tempClothingProducts
          .filter(obj => obj.category.includes('Mens'))

export const clothingProducts = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: 'COMME DES GARCONS TEE',
    img: 'img/product-1.png',
    img2: 'img/product-1-1.png',
    img3: 'img/product-1-2.png',
    img4: 'img/product-1-3.png',
    luxury: 'All Luxury items are inspected to verify authenticity',
    price: 200,
    info: ' COMME DES GARCONS PLAY BASIC LOGO TEE',
    inCart: false,
    count: 0,
    total: 0,
    fabric: '100% Cotton',
    category: 'Mens Fashion'
  }
]
```

Comment: Please add some expected input and output.

Comment: Hey sorry ctrl k just searches google so i have to add the code after

Comment: `.map()` ... no ... do you know what that does? it causes an error `TypeError: missing argument 0 when calling function Array.prototype.map`

Comment: yes it maps through the array

Comment: no, it doesn't, not the way you've written it, because you have no function callback to map ... and it's important that the function returns a value, otherwise you'll end up with a bunch of undefined in the result

Comment: Well i didnt know this thank you

Comment: Jesus the map method was in some code i found while researching and it had parameters that i didnt need so i deleted them

Comment: can you add some sample data

Comment: I did not downvote @TheGreenLightbulb - please don't assume that commenters are downvoters.

Comment: @StackOverflow.

Comment: @TheGreenLightbulb : bro take it easy , i just reverted my  downvote . People will downvote the question when no samples and efforts are seen . You added some samples and now all  good. But very few people will come back to revert it . But keep in mind that the answer you  marked correct will  return true even when the category is "Women fashion"  for "men" input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass a callback to `map` to use it - but here, `map` isn't required at all. Just use `filter`.

```
let tempMensProducts = tempClothingProducts.filter(({ category }) => category.includes("Mens"));
```

If you try to use `map` without a callback, it'll result in an error as it tries to call its argument, and if you don't pass one, it'll try to do `undefined()`.

```js
[1, 2, 3].map();
```

Comment: Okay let me see what the output of the variable is

Comment: Hey how would i add an or to the statement

Comment: let tempMensProducts = tempClothingProducts.filter(({ category,description }) => category.includes("Mens") description.includes("description"));

Comment: something like this

Comment: just a thought , it will match the category "Women fashion" too as it too has "men" there

Answer (score 1):

You can split the array by whitespaces and then apply array `contains` there to sure that it  will give you correct result

I mean to say it should not return "Women" when keyword is "men"

```js
let clothingProducts = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: 'COMME DES GARCONS TEE',
    img: 'img/product-1.png',
    img2: 'img/product-1-1.png',
    img3: 'img/product-1-2.png',
    img4: 'img/product-1-3.png',
    luxury: 'All Luxury items are inspected to verify authenticity',
    price: 200,
    info: ' COMME DES GARCONS PLAY BASIC LOGO TEE',
    inCart: false,
    count: 0,
    total: 0,
    fabric: '100% Cotton',
    category: 'Mens Fashion'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: 'COMME DES GARCONS TEE',
    img: 'img/product-1.png',
    img2: 'img/product-1-1.png',
    img3: 'img/product-1-2.png',
    img4: 'img/product-1-3.png',
    luxury: 'All Luxury items are inspected to verify authenticity',
    price: 200,
    info: ' COMME DES GARCONS PLAY BASIC LOGO TEE',
    inCart: false,
    count: 0,
    total: 0,
    fabric: '100% Cotton',
    category: 'woMens Fashion'
  }
  ]
   let filter = clothingProducts.filter(c => c.category.split(" ").includes("Mens"));
  console.log(filter);
```